# Angular Google Maps - polylines not drawing correctly

Tags: angular, api, maps, polyline

I'm working with AGM to create a detection map, and it's almost working. In the code below you will see I have created objects that carry unique starting points, icons, colors, amd polyline. When I draw out the line, for some reason it starts drawing out, but then goes straight back to its first point.

```
                            resorted.forEach((track) => {
                            let droneKeys = Object.keys(this.drones);
                            if(!droneKeys.includes(track[0].DEVICE_ID)){

                                let iconKeys = Object.keys(this.newStartIcon);
                                let schemeID = iconKeys[Math.floor(Math.random() * iconKeys.length)];
                                console.log(this.newStartIcon[schemeID]);
                                let stroke = this.newStartIcon[schemeID].color;
                                let icon = this.newStartIcon[schemeID].icon;
                                let id = track[0].DEVICE_ID.split('_');
                                let initial = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    map: map,
                                    icon: icon
                                });

                                let poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                              strokeColor: stroke,
                                              strokeOpacity:0.6,
                                              strokeWeight: 3,
                                              map: map
                                            });
                                // the trace line
                                let lineSymbol = {
                                      path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
                                      strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                                      scale: 3
                                    };
                                let stripedPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                    strokeColor: stroke,
                                    strokeOpacity: 0,
                                    icons: [{
                                        icon: lineSymbol,
                                        offset: '0',
                                        repeat: '20px'
                                    }],
                                    map: map
                                });

                                let cluster: any;
                                switch(id[0]){
                                    case 'Unknown':
                                        cluster = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            map: map,
                                            icon: this.droneIcon.unknown,
                                        });
                                        break;
                                    case 'Drone':
                                    case 'Video':
                                        cluster = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            map: map,
                                            icon: this.droneIcon.drone,
                                        });

                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        cluster = new google.maps.Marker({
                                            map: map,
                                            icon: this.droneIcon.controller,
                                        });
                                        break;
                                }

                                this.drones[track[0].DEVICE_ID] = {
                                    initial: initial,
                                    marker: cluster,
                                    line: poly,
                                    stripedLine: stripedPoly,
                                    points: track
                                }
                            } else {
                                this.drones[track[0].DEVICE_ID].points = track;
                            }
                        })
                        this.markers = resorted;
```

This is the forEach loop that creates each individual drone instance

```
    public mapMarkers(map): void {
    for( let drone in this.drones)
    {
        let id = drone.split('_');
        console.log(this.drones[drone]);
        let total       = this.drones[drone].points.length;
        let points      = this.drones[drone].points;
        let marker      = this.drones[drone].marker;
        let line        = this.drones[drone].line;
        let stripedLine = this.drones[drone].stripedLine;
        let initial     = this.drones[drone].initial;

        let path = line.getPath();
        let stripedPath = stripedLine.getPath();

        for(let mark = 0; mark < total; ++mark) {
            let countdown: number = mark*300;
            let coords = new google.maps.LatLng(points[mark].LAT, points[mark].LON);

            setTimeout(() => {
                if((id[0] == 'Controller' || id[0] == 'test1') && mark == total-1){
                    if(!path.b.includes(coords)){
                        marker.setPosition(coords)
                    }
                } else {
                    if(mark == 0 && (id[0] != 'Controller' || id[0] != 'test1')){
                        if(!path.b.includes(coords)){
                            initial.setPosition(coords);
                            path.push(coords);

                        }
                    } else {

                        if(mark <= total-3 && (id[0] != 'Controller' || id[0] != 'test1')){
                            if(!path.b.includes(coords)){
                                marker.setPosition(coords);
                                path.push(coords);
                            }
                            // map.panTo(coords);
                        }  else {
                            if(!stripedPath.b.includes(coords)){
                                stripedPath.push(coords);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }



            }, countdown);
            setTimeout(() => {
                marker.setMap(null);
                initial.setMap(null);
                line.setMap(null);
                stripedLine.setMap(null);
            }, 3000)

        }
    }

}
```

This is the function used to draw the map. Again, it starts drawing, but it always comes back to center and there are usually twice as many points in the polyline than supposed points assigned. Please provide any feed back you can!

here's a visual of the issue I'm having, if it helps at all. 
[image]

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Comment: Unfortunately it's within an even larger system of timers and observables, so it would be hard to display.